# How to make Buildout to leave temporary files around for debugging

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

When running bin/buildout I get

```
Develop: '/fast/vs/zinstance/src/plonetheme.x'
Develop: '/fast/vs/zinstance/src/x.content'
Develop: '/fast/vs/zinstance/src/x.puhelinluettelo'
Updating zope2.
Updating fake eggs
Updating productdistros.
Installing instance.
Getting distribution for 'simplejson==2.0.9'.
No eggs found in /var/folders/3Z/3Z3hsxKxGm8ULSBqCyTuBk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-EOxukI/simplejson-2.0.9/egg-dist-tmp-TCeJDh (setup script problem?)
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'simplejson==2.0.9'.
Error: Couldn't install: simplejson 2.0.9
```

The easy_install temp folder is not available after buildout run. How do I tell buildout not to delete temporary files to inspect the problem? Don't focus on the egg. Manual download of this particular egg works - I want to solve the problem why buildout is doing something I don't understand and fails there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not yet aware of any switch to get it to do this.

Instead, I've manually debugged the process from the python debugger, which not something I can recommend you do unless you enjoy exploring the deep, dark, twisted passages of easy_install, all alike.